# Switch between split views in Kdevelop

Tags: kdevelop, kate

Kdevelop allows for split views (splitting the editor window horizontally or vertically) like known from Emacs and other editors. There are even shortcuts to create such splits (Ctrl+Shift+T, Ctrl+Shift+L), but I couldn't find any shortcut to switch between the splits. Is there any way of defining shortcuts for switching between splits?

Curiously, Kate offers the same split functionality but offers "next split view" and "previous split view" in Settings->Configure Shortscuts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a corresponding [open feature request](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=273385) on bugs.kde.org indicating that this is not yet implemented.

However, [Ctrl]+[Tab], which is used to switch between opened files also switches between split views if the chosen file is opened in another view.